# Energy transfer in form of work or heat?

Tags: statistical-mechanics

Suppose a system A which is a vessel of water with two electrodes, connected by a resistor, placed in the water.

If you apply voltage to the electrodes, energy is transferred from the battery (not included in system A) to system A.

I read in a book that the form of energy transferred is work, and not heat. But basically what happens is that the resistor heats up and transfers heat to the water, am I wrong?

Comment: I think you probably misunderstood the book - both heat and work are forms of energy transfer between systems.

Comment: I do not think the OP misunderstood the book. I think in the book the specific, described set-up was an example for work done on a system. The problem is the subtlety of the work/heat distinction, which, as this case demonstrates depends on the choice of the system!

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, as @Brionius comments, you must have misunderstood the book.

The 1st law of thermodynamics, which sets up the energy balance, says that:

$$\Delta U=Q-W$$

$U$ is internal energy, so $\Delta U$ covers the change in the total *contained* energy in the system. Both **work** $W$ and **heat** $Q$ as you said yourself are methods of *adding* energy to the system.

In you case heat is added to the system, so the internal energy raises, and $\Delta U = Q$. There is no work done $W=0$ if nothing moves (no expansion, motion, rotation, etc).

Comment: One could also argue that work is done at the resistor which causes Joule heating (so in the first place electric work is done on the system which is then irreversibly transformed to heat *in* the system). The resistor is part of the battery according to the description! (But terminology is unclean here as one usually considers only connections thermal bath and mechanical work). After all the work and heat distinction is somewhat artificial.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I have solved the mistery. As the comment of Sebastian Riese suggests the answer depends on whether the resistor is part of the system with the water vessel or part of the system with the battery.

If the wire is part of the water vessel system the work $\Delta W=EMF\cdot\Delta q$, where $EMF$ is the electromotoric force, can be done.

If it is not part of the system, so the wire is excluded from the vessel, only heat transfer is possible.

After all, this subtlety of defining the systems was probably the intended lesson given by the author.